# How does PHP upgrade affect Magento site? I am experiencing problems when I update my phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, magento

Could someone please explain how a PHP upgrade affects a Magento site?

I am developing my Magento site locally on MAMP. For 9 months I have been using the same version of MAMP which uses PHP 5.4.4. I have now upgraded my MAMP to the newest version and it is using PHP 5.5.10.
I now get an error message when I try to access my site. I have a good feeling that this is because of the PHP upgrade.

Please note that I am very much a rookie at programming and know even less about PHP and databases.

Thanks

Comment: What version did you upgrade from? What error message do you now get? Check the PHP [change log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/doc.changelog.php), that's what's changed.

Comment: Upgraded from MAMP 2.1.1. I was able to access my sites home page, but then when I click on another page I get a NOT FOUND error saying 'the requested url was not found on this server'?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the [magento system requirements](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements).

> PHP Compatibility:
>   5.2.13 - 5.3.x, 5.4.x with PATCH

Magento does not support php 5.5, so I guess that's the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have to add a second to the answer above. I just upgraded from MAMP 3.0.7.1 to MAMP 3.5 and my development Magento installation would not work. The default PHP setting for MAMP 3.5 is PHP 7.0.0. When I turn MAMP back one to PHP 5.6.10, it works as it should.